# How to create and populate a jsoncpp array (jsoncpp.sourceforge)

Tags: c++, arrays, jsoncpp

I am trying to create a json cpp array  and populate it with data in a std::vector.

My code looks like this

```
void
Box_20::BuildCommitUploadPostData(const PartInfoColl& partColl)
{
    Json::Value parts;
    parts["parts"] = Json::arrayValue;

    int idx = 0;

    for (const auto& p : partColl) {

        Json::Value partInfo;

        partInfo["part_id"] = p.partId;
        partInfo["offset"] = p.offset;
        partInfo["size"] = p.size;

        parts[idx]["part"] = partInfo;
        idx++;
    }

    /// do more stuff here
}
```

However when I run it, it bombs out.

I can;t see what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: *"it bombs out"* - Care to extend?

Comment: It crashes the first time it executes  parts[idx]["part"] = partInfo;

Answer (score 4):

This worked.

```
void DoSOmeJsonStuff(const PartInfoColl& partColl)
{
    Json::Value parts;

    int idx = 0;

    for (const auto& p : partColl) {

        Json::Value partInfo;

        partInfo["part_id"] = p.partId;
        partInfo["offset"] = p.offset;
        partInfo["size"] = p.size;

        parts[idx]["part"] = partInfo;
        idx++;
    }

    Json::Value root;
    root["parts"] = parts;

    /... 
}
```